# From csv file with text into a dictionary with python

Tags: python, csv

i try to make a dictionery .txt file.
the csv file look like this

the key will be the first part of the row and the value will be the email
i try this

```
with open('file.csv', mode='r',encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    with open('file_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
     writer = csv.writer(outfile)
  
       mydict = {k:v for k, v in rows}
    print(mydict)
```

but a get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

any help will be appreciated

Comment: pfff a feel  stupid... thanks @SleepProgger

Comment: thanks @kaan yuksel bilgin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rows `elements` are not iterable. Thus the error.

Additionally your current code would overwrite mydict each loop and also, as @kaan yuksel bilgin said, you need to set your delimiter properly.

Fixed version:

```
with open('file.csv', mode='r',encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
    with open('arxes_new.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        mydict = {row[0]:row[1] for row in reader if len(row) == 2}
    print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give delimiter parameter to `csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")`. Because when I look at the error message. I assume the problem is this line of code `mydict = {k:v for k, v in rows}`. You are trying to unpack k and v from rows but it turns out rows has 1 element because the default delimiter is ',' and you have no comma in your lines at csv file.